# Bluno <-> Android bluetooth connection failure (Xamarin)

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, bluno

I am connecting to bluno device which streams constant sensor data to my android phone.  Everything seems to be working fine, the connection is established and my xamarin app happily consumes the feed.

After some time though, the bluno appears to stop transmitting.  My transmit function is still being called, if I plug the bluno into a PC I can read the values (read via serial port), but I've tried multiple apps on multiple phones, including the sample BlunoSampleApp, and although they can reconnect to the device and everything appears to be well, no data is being received.

I'm not too familiar with this stuff.  Any idea's on how to figure out what is wrong with my project?  The fault appears to be on the bluno's side, but is there any way to verify whats going on and/or any suggestions on how to fix it?

My android app is implemented in Xamarin, but I don't think thats a factor as the sample app is plain java.

The connection will function anywhere from 20 mins to many hours.  When it stops working, it does not appear that the connection has dropped (my app still reports it is connected) however I just don't receive any more data.  Attempting to reconnect without restarting the bluno reports a successful connection, but does not actually result in new data.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided it was probably my accelerometer (IMU6050) that was killing things.  Somehow either the connection became a bit flunky or something happened - in any case chopping that off allowed the system to run for days without issue.